# How to send data over public IP?

Tags: java, android, tcp, rtp, hole-punching

I am currently working on an **Android app** that needs to transmit data from one device to an other. I want to implement the **data transmission without any server**. I can handle the handshake to exchange the dynamic IPs on my own (Session Initiation) but I am struggling for weeks now how to send the data to the other device when knowing their public and private IP.

For now my app can just send data with **TCP Sockets** to devices within the same WiFi (so just using private IP). But they will get lost once I try to send to public IPs. Probably they can't pass the router's firewall. Turning off the firewall manually is no option. So I guess TCP is the wrong protocol. I think of something like **"Voice over IP"** but with sending any **binary data** instead of just video and audio.

My Ideas were:

1. something like **[Magic-Wormhole](https://magic-wormhole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** because it works like a charm on PC but unfortunately I did not find any way to use it in Android
2. **RTP** (Protocol used for Voice over IP)
3. "UDP **hole punching**" to handle the NAT.

One of those might be the solution. The problem is that I don't know how to implement such things in **Java/Android**

(my [Project](https://github.com/brokkoli71/SendApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/send) on GitHub)

Comment: I would recommend looking into protocols like STUN - basically you need some server that both parties can reach and which can help the devices to connect to each other. Be warned though, the topic is really complicated and it's often difficult to implement these services reliable for all circumstances, which is one reason most big services have central servers!

Comment: do you have any suggestions how to implement such things? I am not able to pay for any servers but have a website with a static IP. Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the internet is really complicated, basically you cannot reach another device by send data to its public IP because most PC or mobile device are behind a NAT.

What you need in such cases is a STUN server, the server can help two devices to communicate to each other in complicated networks. You can create your own STUN server by using open source implementation like STUNTMAN, but its really complicated, so my suggestion is just try a commercial STUN service.

Comment: do you have any suggestions how to make use of any STUN server. I don't need many connections. Unfortunately I can not pay for any services.

Comment: @Brokkoli71 According to Stuntman's official site, a STUN service hosting the Stuntman code is being run at stun.stunprotocol.org (UDP and TCP ports 3478). You can have a try ~

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the Google STUN server for RTP/UDP packet transmission to the network.

[STUN servers: A Quick Start Guide](https://help.singlecomm.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007993947-STUN-servers-A-Quick-Start-Guide)

```
                        Port     URI
STUN Server (Main LB)   19302    stun.l.google.com

STUN Server             19302    stun1.l.google.com

STUN Server             19302    stun2.l.google.com

STUN Server             19302    stun3.l.google.com

STUN Server             19302    stun4.l.google.com
```